# What's my line?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

- I like pies, but I don't like pastries.
- I like gents, but I don't like toffs.
- I like reason, but I don't like rationality.

What have I been doing and how have I been punished?

**Bonus question:**

- One of my friends likes a clean, but he doesn't like a bath or a shower.
- Another of my friends almost likes urges, but he definitely doesn't like temptation,

What's my name?

The punishment in the first part of the question was not literally applied to the individuals in the bonus question. It's for wordplay purposes only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you been

> **Spying** for a foreign nation?

The words you like sure look like it:

> *S*-pies
>  *A*-gents
>  *T*-reason

And a common punishment for that used to be what was done to those words too:

> **Off with their heads!**

Using the same logic, the friends in the bonus questions might then be

> [Donald *M*-aclean and Guy *B*-urges(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_Five)

which would then make you

> Kim Philby, one of the more notorious spies of the 20th century.